# Creating a category drop down field in Ruby on Rails, using nested forms and has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, has-many-through

**Edit: It looks like defining @categories again in the task's create method did the trick of clearing up the error. Still working on actually having the category update when I submit the task, because right now it's ignoring it. Any ideas?**

Hi all,

I'm trying to create a drop down list in my first Rails project in order to select from a list of categories for a task. I've used a Categorization model to link the Task model with a Category.

After some effort, I've gotten the drop down to show up properly on the new task form, but when I hit submit, the form gives the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Tasks#create

You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.map
```

Any help you could provide is really appreciated. Here is the code I'm using (excerpted for brevity)...

**The relevant part of my new task form (HAML):**

```
= f.fields_for :categorization do |sub|
    = sub.label :name, 'Category'
    = sub.collection_select(:category_id, @categories, :id, :name, :include_blank => 'Select a Category')
```

**tasks_controller.rb:**

```
def new
    @task = Task.new
    @categories = Category.all
end

def create
    @task = current_user.tasks.build(params[:task])
    if @task.save
        flash[:success] = "Task created!"
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

**categorization.rb:**

```
class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :task
    belongs_to :category

    validates :task_id, :presence => true
    validates :category_id, :presence => true
end
```

**category.rb:**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :categorizations, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :tasks, :through => :categorizations

    validates :name, :presence => true
end
```

**task.rb**

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :title, :body

    has_many :categorizations, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :categories, :through => :categorizations

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :categorizations

    validates :title, :presence => true
    validates :body, :presence => true
end
```

**routes.rb:**

```
resources :tasks

resources :categories do
    member do
        get :tasks
    end
end
```

Any thoughts? Thank you so much for taking a look, and let me know if you need anything else to help.

Haidn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I'm going to try figuring out correctly implementing the save on my own, but I discovered the solution for my original problem, which was declaring @categories again in my Task create method. Hopefully that helps somebody!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to need to add the following line to your categorization.rb:

```
attr_accessible :category_id
```

Without that line, you cannot set the category_id in the build method you are using in tasks_controller.rb

Let me know if that fixes it for you!

Comment: Apologies:  this is the blind leading the blind here. Given you have no 'attr_accessible' call, all the attributes are available - so my advice certainly isn't the solution.  One thing I just noticed, though: `include_blank => 'Select a Category'` should be  `{include_blank => 'Select a Category'}`.  Not sure this fix your problem, though.

Comment: Hi @Rob, unfortunately the braces didn't change the functionality, and you're correct in seeing that I don't have any attr_accessible characteristics set at the moment. I appreciate the effort, though! Let me know if you think of anything else.